# Domain of joint continuous random variables - Geometrically

Tags: probability, statistics

Given the joint P.D.F of $X$ and $Y$:

$f_{X,Y}(x,y) = 6x^2y\ \ (x,y) \in (0,1) \times (0,1)$

$f_{X,Y}(x,y) = 0$ elsewhere

The following double integral should be the probability of $P(Y>2X)$ :

$P(Y > 2X) = \int_0^1 \! \int_0^{y/2} 6x^2y \, \mathrm{d}x \mathrm{d}y$

However what I don't understand is why $X$ takes values from $0$ to $y/2$.

I tried to sketch the corresponding area - upper left triangle of $1\times 1\ $ square above $Y = 2X$ - and my best guess is that for each value of $Y$ then $X = \frac{Y}{2}$

Finally how would one calculate the **$P(Y<2X)$** area where $X$ and $Y$ move?

Right now what I struggle with is finding the corresponding area of $R^2$ regardless of the problem/question

Comment: For any given value of $X$ you need to look at all values of $Y$ that are less than the value we have chosen for $X$. For $X$ we can pick whatever we like, thus, $\int_0^1$. On the other hand, $y$ needs to be smaller than the value of $X$, hence $\int_0^x$. Now if we have $X>2Y$, you need to change to $\int_0^{y/2}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> However what I don't understand is why $X$ takes values from $0$ to $y/2$.

Because you want to integrate over $\{\langle x,y\rangle\in(0..1)^2:y>2x\}$ which is also $\{\langle x,y\rangle\in(0..1)^2:x<y/2\}$

$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(Y>2X)&=\mathsf P(X<Y/2)\\&=\int_0^1\int_0^{y/2} 6x^2y\;\mathrm dx\;\mathrm d y\end{align}$$

> Finally how would one calculate the **$P(Y<2X)$** area where $X$ and $Y$ move?

You want to integrate over $\{\langle x,y\rangle: 0<y<\min\{1,2x\}<2\}$ which *may* be done by parting that domain into a union of disjoint domains...

$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(Y<2X)&=\int_0^{1/2}\int_0^{2x}6x^2y\;\mathrm dy\;\mathrm d x+\int_{1/2}^1\int_0^1 6x^2y\;\mathrm dy\;\mathrm dx\end{align}$$

**Or** of course...

$$\mathsf P(Y<2X)=1-\mathsf P(Y>2X)\color{silver}{\require{cancel}\cancelto0{+\mathsf P(Y=2X)}}$$

Comment: Can you help me see this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4500939/can-we-take-the-coupling-of-mu-and-nu? Thank you!